# ¿Es necesario realizar todo el mapeo de todas las tablas con hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

Buenas a todos,

He estado revisando una aplicación de Spring + Hibernate y según veo hay muchas tablas que no están mapeadas o que no cuentan con una entidad definida en Java. También he visto que muchas de ellas no cuentan ni siquiera con la relación OneToOne, OneToMany, etc... Desde mi punto de vista creo que cada tabla debe tener su entidad para aprovechar de mejor forma las bondades de Hibernate o al menos eso es lo que realizan en muchos cursos.

- ¿Se debe tener una entidad por cada tabla para aprovechar Hibernate?
- ¿Existe en la documentación de manera específica algo que trate sobre esto?

Gracias a todos

Comment: si es necesario mapear las entidades siempre cuando las necesites pero si no se necesita, es aconsejable volver a estructurar la base de datos para eliminar y no llenar de basura a hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

Todo depende de la configuración de tu proyecto, hibernate al final es una capa de abstracción sobre la base de datos que puedes decidir explotar o no. Eso ya depende de cada empresa y de cada proyecto, se pueden seguir varios enfoques con hibernate que dependen de la configuración en el application.properties o el .yml de tu proyecto:

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto
```

Este valor es el que define cuán restrictivo es hibernate en tu proyecto y puede tomar varios valores:

**create:** Hibernate gestiona la base de datos, es decir, cuando levantas el proyecto, lo que tengas en tu base de datos **se borra** e hibernate crea tu esquema de datos en base a las entidades.

**update:** Hibernate chequea tu base de datos y tus entidades, la base de datos no la toca ni borra nada. Luego Hibernate revisa las entidades y comprueba si cada entidad y cada campo existen en la base de datos, si no existen los crea pero respetando lo que ya existe. En este enfoque tus entidades no tienen que coincidir con la base de datos, si tienes una entidad con menos columnas que en base de datos no pasa absolutamente nada.

**validate:** Hibernate no crea nada en base de datos nunca, lo único que hace es chequear que los tipo de datos y nombres en tus entidades sean correctos con la base de datos. si tienes un campo como Integer en tu entidad pero que es varchar2 en bbdd, hibernate generará un error y no te dejará levantar el proyecto.

Así que la respuesta a tu pregunta es que hibernate acepta varios enfoques y es decisión de la arquitectura de la aplicación cuál quieres adoptar.

Answer (score 1):

Hay tantas soluciones como colores. Debes entender que hibernate te permite "modelar" tu base de datos con objetos java. Pero este modelo no tiene por que *ser un reflejo de la realidad* y, aunque lo sea, hay varias formas de hacerlo. Te pongo un ejemplo: Si queremos modelar una relación "n a n" podemos modelarlo:

- Con 2 entidades y unas anotaciones @manytomany
- Con 3 entidades y anotaciones @ManyToOne (modelando la tabla intermedia)
- Modelando la relación no como objetos sino como un atributo de tipo ID

Y estas son solo algunas de las posibilidades. Hay muchas más. Es posible que ni siquiera queramos que nuestra aplicación sepa de la existencia de la relación, o de alguna de las tablas. Solemos pensar que cuando creamos una aplicación la base de datos es nuestra, pero ten en cuenta que a lo mejor estás haciendo una aplicación que solo hace uso de una parte de la base de datos, porque el sistema es enorme y tu solo manejas una parte.

Dicho esto:

- ¿Se debe tener una entidad por cada tabla para aprovechar Hibernate?
  No. Puedes hacer muchas cosas (malas y buenas). Puedes tener varias entidades por una sola tabla. Puedes no tener ninguna si nunca vas a utilizarla. Puedo tener una entidad que modela la tabla Usuarios sin relaciones para consultas rápidas con 2 o tres campos y otra que modela las relaciones con roles de forma que siempre se las traiga enlazadas (esto evitaría que te tuvieras que preguntar en tiempo de ejecución si la lista de roles ha venido de base de datos o no). Si la pregunta es cuando hago una cosa u otra... Esa es la pregunta maestra!! Depende mucho de que estés haciendo, lo que es una mala practica en un entorno es aconsejable en otros. Lo mejor es plantearse la pregunta con un problema concreto.
- ¿Existe en la documentación de manera específica algo que trate sobre esto?
  No. La [documentación de Hibernate](http://hibernate.org/orm/documentation/5.2/) te va a explicar como y que puedes hacer, pero como ya te he dejado entre-ver lo que hagas con esa información es cosa tuya. Encontrarás miles de artículos que te explican como modelar ciertos problemas, generalmente basados en modelarlo todo con el menor numero de clases, teniendo muchas relaciones en todas las clases. Desde mi humilde opinión lo mejor es modelar lo que te hace falta, si usas una tabla de 2 formas distintas a lo mejor tienes que plantearte modelarla de dos formas distintas (o cambiar la base de datos, pero no voy a entrar en eso). Para saber decidir lo mejor es la experiencia de que en el proyecto anterior modelaste las cosas de una forma y funcionó bien, o terminó generando problemas, lógicas poco claras, etc...

Answer (score 0):

En hibernate se debe tener una Clase por cada Tabla que vas a persistir y que no te genere mas dependencias hacia otras tablas. Una vez que tengas todas las tablas que vas a persistir en base de datos, si son demasiadas existe la [Ingenieria Inversa Hibernate](https://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-generate-code-with-hibernate-tools/) y con eso hibernate genera todas las clases y mapeos para lo que vas a persistir. Si hay tablas que no utilizas no generes esos mapeos.

Comment: ¿En cualquier aplicación? Incluyendo Grails y esas ondas?

Comment: No conozco Grails